# Getting list of modified files

Tags: google-drive-api, eventual-consistency, filelist

I am trying to use google drive API to get a list of files which were changed inside a folder.

When using the query "modifiedTime > `some_ts`" it sometimes takes several minutes until I see the changes in the data: meaning that on the first query I will get 0 files and after several minutes (could even be 15) I get the changed file.

I tried getting the entire file list without a specific query and using the `modifiedTime` parameter to decide if the file was changed or not. 
I always get the modification ts, but strangely sometimes it changes between the first run to the second one, mostly a difference of 5 seconds but still very strange.

Has anyone have any idea why this is happening \ a way to get all the changed files inside a folder?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the [Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) module.

> For Google Drive apps that need to keep track of changes to files, the [Changes collection](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes) provides an efficient way to detect changes to all files, including those that have been shared with a user. The collection works by providing the current state of each file, if and only if the file has changed since a given point in time.

Be noted that it requires a `pageToken` to indicate a point in time to fetch changes from. To request the page token for the current state of the account, call [`changes.getStartPageToken`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken). Store and use this token in the initial call to [`changes.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list).

[**Retrieving changes**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes#retrieving_changes)

> To retrieve the list of changes for the currently authenticated user, send a GET request to the changes collection, as detailed in the [List reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list).

Check the documentation for sample codes.